# How to reference SMF libraries when deploying on phone 7 (Release)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, reference

Initially, at Visual Studio, I clicked debug instead of release to deploy my app on phone 7 device. No errors, works perfectly fine!

Received multitude of errors that mention that some of the libraries don't seem to exist on the mobile phone.

For example, extract from the entire list of errors include

```
Warning 10  The referenced component 'Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Utilities' could not be found. 

Warning 3   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  SLARToolKitWinPhoneSample
```

In addition, im also using Slartookit to power up the AR capabilities. Deploying (Release) on the mobile prompts the following errors too.

```
Error   11  The type or namespace name 'SLARToolKit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What should I do? Will updating the mobile solve this? Do I have to manually install? Or?

Thanks

Comment: Weird, even though im still getting those errors, app still seems to be working fine. But still great to solve them, might impact in later developments. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any referenced third party assemblies, they should be automatically copied to the XAP. You can open the generated XAP with any kind of zip-file tool, to ensure the assembly been correctly copied over at the build.

If it's GAC referenced assemblies, you might want to reference them locally instead.